# Case statement using different columns in Talend

Tags: talend

I have a case statement as below

Case when col1 like '%other%' then 'No' else col5 end as col5

Here like in SQL I need to implement the case statement with different columns and the wild card check of the word 'other' all in talend how can this be done?

Comment: Are the columns always dynamic? Do you know the words to look for?

Comment: The columns are not dynamic, I want to look out for words like "other, please specify", "others not required" so I have to look out for other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are not dynamically created, you can add a case in *tMap* for example.

So, for a new boolean column you could create the expression:

```
row1.mycolumn1.toLowerCase().contains("other") ? new Boolean.true : new Boolean.false;
```

The boolean field would hold the check value then.

**EDIT**

Since a new boolean column is not wanted here, your specific requirement would look like this:

```
row1.product_code.toLowerCase().contains("other") ? "No data" : row1.product_code;
```

Comment: Hi Tobi, it's not a boolean column where I have to output my data. I'll explain, if product_category has the word 'other' in its text then the product_code  should be set to 'No data'

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, without any screenshots or explanation.
I assume that you have some input component, like tOracleInput with row out of it, having multiple columns in the schema. I would suggest to use tMap component to manipulate contents of the schema, especially Expression Builder.

P.S. I personally prefer tJavaFlex for columns validations / manipulations, this way the code more readable, but it is more advanced technique.

Comment: My source is  tfileinputdelimited and destination is tfileoutputdelimited. I will have to perform say check column product_category, if it has words 'other' then in product_code set value as 'No data'

Answer (score 0):

Please find the input as follows.
col1            col2    col3    col4    col5
----            ----    ----    ----    ----
aaaother    aaa aaa aaa aaa 
otherbbb    bbb bbb bbb bbb 
ccc         ccc ccc ccc ccc

in the tMap you have to have the following statement in the expression builder against col5

***`input.col1.contains("other")?"No":input.col5`***

then the output will be as follows

col1            col2    col3    col4    col5
----            ----    ----    ----    ----
aaaother    aaa aaa aaa No  
otherbbb    bbb bbb bbb No  
ccc         ccc ccc ccc ccc